# why iphone videos are not playing in some of the android phones.?

Tags: android, iphone, video

While i'm playing recorded videos of both android and iphone. Iphone videos are not playing in some of the android phones like sony,htc,nexus.Videos is in mp4 format.I have checked different formats as well but nothing works.Showing an mediaplayer error  (1, -2147483648) in android.can anyone sort the problem whether it is phone problem or uploading video in server or anything else???

here is my logcat:

12-25 16:18:52.518: E/MediaPlayer(27130): error (1, -2147483648)
12-25 16:18:52.518: E/MediaPlayer(27130): Error (1,-2147483648)
12-25 16:18:52.518: D/VideoView(27130): Error: 1,-2147483648

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's because of incompatible codec problems. Try using web-m format.

Comment: whether video should be uploaded in web-m format or to play video in web-m format?@AVEbrahimi

Comment: should be uploaded in web-m format.

Comment: i have tested in web-m format also but it doesnot work,same error is displaying.@AVEbrahimi

Comment: please any one help me over this..